# Missing over-effect after switched div (jquery draggable/droppable)

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, droppable

I´m using jquery´s draggable and droppable for implementing a drag'n'drop -functionality:
There are two tabs, each containing a droppable-zone with draggables. Now I can pick a draggable a move it to the other tab - the tab changes when I move over the tab during the drag-process. (Just like MS WinExplorer if you move a file from one directory to another one....). To indicate that the user is above a droppable-zone I use the hoverClass-option.

The problem: After changing the tabs several times during dragging the hover effect is missing. If the browser-size requires scroll bars and I move the pointer with the draggable to one of the browser-borders (so that the browser scrolls) the hover-effect is shown... . I´ve added the over-event to the droppable to check whether this is always fired - but it isn´t.

```
$('.drag').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    helper: function () {
        return $('<div></div>').addClass('drag-dragging').appendTo('body').text($(this).text());
    }
});

$('#panel-1-droppable,#panel-2-droppable').droppable({
    accepts: 'drag',
    hoverClass: 'panel-dropover',
    over: function () {
        // just to check the over-event
        $('#over-state').text('Mouseover with draggable [' + $(this).attr('id') + ']');
    }
});

$('.panel-tab').droppable({
    over: function () {
        // changing tab...
    }
});
```

I´ve created a test-scenario to reproduce the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/CKYJs/5/

I´ll hope I´ve provided all necessary information ...

Comment: Isnt the plugin sortable from jQuery UI not what u need? It has the main functionality you want to achieve.. so you can manipulate the rest of the functionality? see here: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists-through-tabs

Comment: jquery-sortable could be a solution. But i´m still looking for a solution to get my current implemenation working. There are "special" dropzones I need to recreate using sortable (without any idea at the moment...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved setting refreshPositions on TRUE.

http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-refreshPositions